# Calling the Microsoft.Azure.Fluent APIs using an existing token

Tags: azure, token, fluent

I am using the Microsoft.Azure…Fluent packages to make REST API calls to Azure.  Currently I am using the following to initialize my IAzure object:

```
            var Credentials = SdkContext.AzureCredentialsFactory.FromServicePrincipal(
                appID,
                secret,
                tenantID,
                AzureEnvironment.AzureGlobalCloud);

            Azure = Microsoft.Azure.Management.Fluent.Azure
                .Configure()
                .WithLogLevel(HttpLoggingDelegatingHandler.Level.Basic)
                .Authenticate(Credentials)
                .WithSubscription(subscriptionID);
```

Is it possible to initialize the Azure object using an existing 'on-behalf-of' token instead of using the Client ID, Client Secret?

Answer (score 0):

The front end web app is able to obtain both a graph token as well as the ARM token so I'm able to get it working as follows:

```
            var customTokenProvider = new AzureCredentials(
                                    new TokenCredentials(**armToken**),
                                    new TokenCredentials(**graphToken**),
                                    tenantID,
                                    AzureEnvironment.AzureGlobalCloud);

            Azure = Microsoft.Azure.Management.Fluent.Azure
                .Configure()
                .WithLogLevel(HttpLoggingDelegatingHandler.Level.Basic)
                .Authenticate(customTokenProvider)
                .WithSubscription(subscriptionID);
```